# mac os x 10.6.8 and “adb devices” fails to list android device when Motorola Atrix running Android 2.2.2 connected

Tags: android

I am on a iMac running OS X v10.6.8 and I am connecting a Motorola Atrix running Android 2.2.2  but for some reason, when I run adb devices on the terminal, it does not list the Motorola Atrix. Other android devices are easily detected and listed.

Comment: Have you tried it on a different computer? Just making sure its to a port/cable problem.

Comment: Yes. I just tried it on a Windows machine running Windows 7 and even though it said that the drivers installed successfully, it does not list the device when I run adb.

Comment: And you've got it in debug mode on device as well as checked that the PC/Mac can see the SD card when mounted.